# Gracefully restart entire Akka actor system

Tags: akka

How can I gracefully restart an entire actor system? In other words, stop all the actors in the system with a `gracefulStop` (or at least the important ones!)

Basically I want to, in effect, restart the application during a test, without the overhead of starting up a new separate JVM each time.

I'm using Akka 2.0.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you have implemented an actor system and it is lacking one function, don’t hesitate to add one more actor to take care of that: in this case create one actor whose job is it to send graceful stop requests to your important actors and await their termination. That actor can then shut down the actor system, while from the outside you `awaitTermination`. If you created that actor with `system.actorOf(Props[Terminator], "terminator")`, then you can shut it down with

```scala
system.actorFor("/user/terminator") ! MakeItStop // or whatever message you choose
try system.awaitTermination(1.minute) // or however long it may take
catch {
  case _: TimeoutException => system.shutdown() // as a last resort
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's for unit test you can just stop the ActorSystem and start a new one.

```
val system1 = ActorSystem("system1")
system1.shutdown() // This is async and will return before the system actually stops.

val system2 = ActorSystem("system2")
```

I'm not sure how you can restart the system (actually, I'm not sure the above would work, but I see no reason for it not to).

Comment: I need to make sure the important actors are allowed to stop gracefully.

Comment: Use `postStop`: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#stop-hook

Comment: There is an awaitTermination method available on ActorSystem that blocks the current thread until the system has been shutdown. There is also a registerOnTermination method to register a listener for shutdowns.